# How do i output one value if one has been used?

Tags: python

I am starting out with python and tried to make a heads or tails game with little understanding so i could get used to it. I am trying find out a way to output one value (heads) if the other has already been used (tails).

Here is part of my code, i need help with P2:

```
P1 = str(input("P1, please enter Heads or Tails "))
if P1 in ['Heads','heads','HEADS']:
    print("You are Heads")
elif P1 in ['Tails','TAILS','tails']:
     print("You are Tails")
else:
    print("Oops, Thats not right")
    exit()
time.sleep(1)
P2 = str(input("P2, please enter heads or tails"))





time.sleep(1)
print("The coin has been flipped")
time.sleep(1)
HoT = random.randint(1,2)
if HoT == 1:
    print ("heads wins")
else:
    print("tails wins")
time.sleep(1)
exit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "already used"? Can you give an example of what the user(s) might type, what should happen as a result, and how that is different from what currently happens? It sounds like you want player 2 to use whichever option wasn't chosen by player 1, but now I'm confused. There's only one option remaining, so why are you asking player 2 a question at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to display which (heads or tails) player 2 will be you can use an `if` statement, as you have done at the start of your code:

```
# after P1 has chosen...
if P1 in ['Heads','heads','HEADS']:
    P2 = "tails"
else:
    P2 = "heads"

print("P2 you are {}".format(P2))
```

You can also use the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

```
# after P1 has chosen...
P2 = "tails" if P1 in ['Heads','heads','HEADS'] else "heads"
print("P2 you are {}".format(P2))
```

Comment: okay thank you, i realised that i dont need to ask player 2 a question because there  is only one option left and i could just tell them which it is. but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly, here is what you could try.

```
out = 'Heads' if P1.lower() == 'tails' else 'Tails'

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import random, time

P1 = input("P1, please enter Heads or Tails ")
if P1.lower() == 'heads':
    print("You are Heads")
elif P1.lower() == 'tails':
     print("You are Tails")
else:
    print("Oops, Thats not right")
    exit()
time.sleep(1)

P2 = 'heads' if P1.lower() == 'tails' else 'tails' # Here is the condiiton

time.sleep(1)
print("The coin has been flipped")
time.sleep(1)
HoT = random.randint(1,2)
if HoT == 1:
    print ("heads wins")
else:
    print("tails wins")
time.sleep(1)
exit()
```